# Numeric Format Strings - Align Positive and Negative Numbers when using Perenthesis like Excel using C#

Tags: c#, format-string

With Excel, I can create a nice numeric format string with parentheses as follows:

```
0_);(0)
```

This create a space on the right of positive numbers that is the same width as a parenthesis so that they line up correctly with the parenthesis of negative numbers.

With C#, I am using the following format string:

```
string Output = SomeNumber.ToString("0 ;(0)");
```

This inserts a space after the positive number.  However, if the Space has a different width as a parenthesis, the numbers don't align perfectly.

How do I create a literal in the C# format string that is a blank space the same width as a parenthesis?

Comment: Surely this has not much to do with format strings, and everything to do with whatever method is being used to display the resulting strings.

Comment: You'll have to use the proper font.  A fixed-pitch font like Consolas or Courier New will always work.

Answer (score -1):

You could find the unicode character for a space with the same width as the parenthesis (punctuation space)

https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html

and put that unicode character into your string

Comment: Your link says that's "The width of a period “.”" so why do you claim in your answer that it's the width of a parenthesis? Or are you claiming that a period and a parenthesis have the same width in all fonts? They don't.

Comment: I am claiming only that a unicode space could solve the problem, and that I possibly incorrectly assumed that a parenthesis would count as punctuation. I certainly did not claim that a period and parenthesis have the same width in all fonts, in fact the word font is not mentioned in the question, or my answer.

Comment: I would also point out that I do not see how your comment addresses the question. Assuming both the positive and negative numbers and parentheses are in the same font the problem will still exist.

Comment: Okay, let me re-start from scratch: this is a useless answer. "The unicode character for a space with the same width as the parenthesis" does not exist. Your link does not claim it exists. You do not have anything in your answer to support your claim that it does exist. You're right that my comment doesn't answer the question. It's not supposed to. Comments aren't supposed to answer the question, answers are supposed to answer the question, and yours doesn't.

Comment: Let me restart from scratch: I cannot comment, I can only answer - because I only started using this site properly in earnest today. I would have preferred to comment also. It was an idea. You think it's useless. I get it. Marking me down just leads my only route to contributing creating further answers that could have been comments.